# java.lang.AssertionError: Response content expected:<TestVersion> but was:<>

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit4

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class VersionResourceImplTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class MockConfig {
        @Bean
        public Properties myProp() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("ra.bank.app.version", "TestVersion");
            return properties;
        }
    }

    @Value("#{myProp['ra.bank.app.version']}")
    private String applicationVersion;

    @Test
    public void testVersion() {
        Assert.assertEquals("TestVersion", applicationVersion);
    }

}
```

This is my test file. It is giving the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content expected:<TestVersion> but was:<>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers$5.match(ContentResultMatchers.java:149)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.db.creditrisk.rating.analysis.bank.ui.facade.v2.common.ws.VersionResourceImplTest.shouldReturnCorrectVersion(VersionResourceImplTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: I think you should use @Value("${ra.bank.app.version}")
private String applicationVersion;

Comment: property file is not getting injected in my case...can you suggest something for this?

Comment: you don't have to create object for properties. you can use application.properties and there you can specify version details and then @value("${ra.bank.app.version}") will work.

Comment: yes I removed the properties object...and added test.properties -ra.bank.app.version=TestVersion
with this value but still getting null

Comment: i have provided you one solution in answer tab can you please check again and do let me know if it works.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you please share your full code again?which you are trying now.

Comment: Hey @GauravRai1512 I just copy pasted yours given below...it is same as you asked to try

Comment: Okie @Supriya let me check again

Answer (score 0):

For `app.version=version2` in properties file we read it using `@Value` annotation like below.

```
@Value("${app.version}")
private String appVersion;
```

So things to troubleshoot for your issue are.

1.Ensure that the property file is present in your classpath.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

OR

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

2.Print the value before assert statement to know whether @Value is really injecting value or not.

3.Change `@Value("#{myProp['ra.bank.app.version']}")` to `@Value("${ra.bank.app.version}")`

Comment: i did that but now I am getting the following error- VersionResourceImplTest.testVersion:43 expected:<TestVersion> but was:<null>

Comment: Check point 2 .. system.out.print before assert statement and check what value you get

Comment: I am getting null there

Comment: property file is not getting injected as I am getting null value

Comment: @Supriya why don't you use application.properties of spring-boot which i have explained above.

Comment: Yes..I knew this...so now search for how to load properties

Comment: I tried using but not able to retrieve values from test.properties

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code and let me know if it's works.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = VersionResourceImplTest.myProp.class)
  @TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "ra.bank.app.version=TestVersion",
})
    public class VersionResourceImplTest {

        @Value("${ra.bank.app.version}")
        private String applicationVersion;

        @Test
        public void testVersion() {
            Assert.assertEquals("TestVersion", applicationVersion);
        }

@Configuration
    public static class myProp{
        @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    }

    }
```

or you can also use below approach as well.

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "ra.bank.app.version=TestVersion"
})
public class FooTest {

  @Value("${ra.bank.app.version}")
  String applicationVersion;

  @Test
  public void testVersion() {
    Assert.assertEquals("TestVersion", applicationVersion);
 }

}
```

Comment: I tried both ways...With ist approach I get null only ..means values are not getting picked from property file and in second approach I get failed to load applicationContext error